# Angular 7 can't set value for mat-select form control

Tags: angular, angular7, formgroups

I have this form group with several form controls:

```
myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    ...
    myControl: new FormControl(),
    ...
  });
```

The form control `myControl` is this:

```
<mat-form-field class="col-large">
            <mat-select formControlName="myControl">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let data of dataMap" [value]="data.value">
                {{data.description}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
```

The `dataMap` is basically an array of objects that have a property value and a property description, both of them are strings, so an example of object is:

```
{
  "value":"1",
  "description":"desc"
}
```

Then I have an autocomplete input that works on the same `dataMap` and, whenever the user starts typing, it searches through the descriptions of the array, prompting only the ones that matches with the text written. Then, when the user selects an option, it calls a method that retrieves the correspondent value from the array and sets the value retrieved for `myControl`. The expected behaviour is that, when an option in the autocomplete is selected, the value is changed in `myControl` and a new description is shown.
The problem is that the value for `myControl` is correctly set, but no selected option is showed.
What I do not understand is that in the ngOnInit method I set a default value from the map for `myControl` this way:

```
this.myForm.get('myControl').setValue("1");
```

and it correctly select the option and shows it as selected. Then, in the callback method for the autocomplete selection, I do the same but it is not selected. The form control goes blank.
I've checked the value I get from the autocomplete and it exists in `dataMap`. I've also printed the value for `myControl` after setting the new value and it is the correct new one.

Comment: We can't debug code without seeing the code.

Comment: I know, but I can't post the code and the data ... I'll try to adjust it but I don't know if I'll manage to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this instead

```
let test = {
  "value":"1",
  "description":"desc"
}

this.myForm.get('myControl').setValue(test);
```

you should pass the same type of object to the myControl